How to use ADB and shell to obtain data from a specified memory address of a designated app within an Android emulator?
How to use ADB and shell to obtain data from a specified memory address of a designated app within an Android emulator?
I hope to access and retrieve data from a specified memory address within the Android emulator and feed it back to the PC using ADB and shell.
2. Scan the memory within the Android emulator to search for specified values.
Can the above functions be implemented in Python or C++?

I don't think adb shell has the permission to dump memory of arbitrary app processes. That may work for apps marked as debug=true but not for regular apps. For those you need root access and e.g. use https://frida.re
